# Linked list program flow with respect program stack execution

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, linked-list, stack-trace

```
static void just_traverse(sll **head_ref) {
    sll *first = *head_ref;
    sll *second = (*head_ref)->next;

    if(second == NULL) {
            return;
    }

    just_traverse(&(second));
    *head_ref = second;
    printf("%d \t",second->payload);
}
```

In above code if I remove *head_ref = second; I get output with respect to stack however If I put this line *head_ref = second; It always print last element say {4,3,2,1} then it always prints 1?Can anybody explain why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? if you just traversing why do you pass ** and not sll * ? what's the definition of sll?

Comment: This code is part of recursive reverse linked list.can anybody please tell me why "second" pointer never changes

Comment: If you really need to reverse and not just output values in reverse order. I posted few changes you need to do in you programm in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Your list contains {4,3,2,1}, then your output should be `1 1 1` right.

This because of the statement `*head_ref = second;`. In the 3rd call to the function `just_traverse` `head_ref` will points to `2` and `second` will points to `1`. Now you are updating `**head_ref` to `1`. Now you are printing `second`. So output will be value `1`

And then it will return to the 2nd call, here `head_ref` is `3` and `second` is `1` (not `2` becuase we updated in 3rd all). Now againg assigning `1` to head and printing `second`. Again it will print the value `1` only.

And then it will return to the 1st call, here `head_ref` is `4` and `second` is `1` (not `3` because we updated in 2nd call). Now againg assigning `1` to head and printing `second`. Again it will print the value `1` only.

So the output will be three `1`

```
1 1 1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have question "And then it will return to the 2nd call, here head_ref is 2 and second is 1 (not 2 becuase we updated in 3rd all)." But in third call we updated *head_ref not second i.e.  *head_ref = second; so why value of "second" does not change

Comment: @error_404 : In 3rd call you updated **head_ref, which is nothing but `second` in 2nd call. Because we are calling 3rd call by passing address of `second` from 2nd call. And also upvote the answer, if like it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may try to debug to figure out why you set pointer incorrectly.
2. Likely it should be the following

   just_traverse(&(second));
   second->next = first;
   first->next = NULL;

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to make it too complex - this isn't tested, but is at least a simpler pattern for doing a recursive reverse-walk on a singly linked list:

```
static void just_traverse(sll *head_ref) {
    if (head_ref == NULL) {
            return;
    }

    just_traverse(head_ref -> next);

    printf("%d \t",head_ref->payload);
}
```